# Keyval undefined error

Tags: beamer

I am new to Beamer. When I run a sample code:

```
\begin{frame} 
\begin{itemize}
\item Assuming equal power allocation at the source \vspace{0.2cm}
\item Water-filling scheme at the relays over spatial \& temporal domains \vspace{0.1cm}
\item IAPC at each relay puts a lid on the water vessel
\end{itemize}
\begin{columns}[2]
\column{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Relays are rarely used at very low \& high SNRs \vspace{0.2cm}
    \item Stronger relay is used more often \vspace{0.2cm}
\end{itemize}
\column{0.6\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figures/Pon/Pon_naf1_c.eps}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

I get error: `Package keyval Error: 2 undefined \end{frame}`. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: It's complaining about `[2]` you don't need to tell beamer how many columns there are, it just sees the nested column environments (which should be environments, not commands)

Answer (score 10):

Please always post complete documents, not just fragments. (Here I use `draft` so the figure is not included)

As noted in comments the error message is telling you that the `[2]` argument is incorrect,
you do not specify the number of columns in beamer.

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft]{beamer}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Assuming equal power allocation at the source \vspace{0.2cm}
\item Water-filling scheme at the relays over spatial \& temporal domains \vspace{0.1cm}
\item IAPC at each relay puts a lid on the water vessel
\end{itemize}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Relays are rarely used at very low \& high SNRs \vspace{0.2cm}
    \item Stronger relay is used more often \vspace{0.2cm}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figures/Pon/Pon_naf1_c.eps}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

In some cases I have found that more recent versions of `beamer`/`keyval` are more picky about what is defined or not. You can pass the option `unknownkeysallowed` to beamer to stop some of these messages.

Edit: to pass the option try

```
\documentclass[unknownkeysallowed]{beamer}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: You should add a example to your answer. As this, and for me, this is not an answer.in fact it's where you should add `unknownkeysallowed` `;)`

Comment: I can't find anything in the source suggesting that a simple number of columns here has every been allowed: do you know that it was?

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting that this doesn't actually do anything at the `beamer` end, it just turns the `keyval` error into a piece of info in the log file.