# Backward compatibility of Beamer problem - Keyval error

Tags: beamer, key-value

I'm stuck with a problem for compiling a "not so old" beamer document I've made last year, and it seems that there is a big problem of backward compatibility between my new version of beamer (3.33) and the one I used before (3.24).
here is a minimalist example that compile with the older version and not the newer :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
      \tableofcontents[currentsection,othersections,hideothersubsections,hidesubsections]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[margin=0pt]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

here are the relevant output of the compiler :

the older :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27> 
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 6 languages loaded. 
Document Class: beamer 2012/10/15 development version 3.24 A class for typesett ing presentations (rcs-revision 24853e6b98cf)
```

the newer :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
[...] 
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27> Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 6 languages loaded.
[...] 
Document Class: beamer 2013/12/02 3.33 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision 332bfd3ce558)
[...] 
! Package keyval Error: othersections undefined. 
[...] 
! Package keyval Error: margin undefined.
```

There are a other keys that trigger exactly the same kind of error (bg, fg).
Is it a known problem ? 
I could'nt find relevant answer on the web, and would welcome any solution other than keep compiling on my old computer or rewrite my presentations. 
Maybe a package to load, or somthing like that ? or a magic incantation ?

Thanks for reading, many thanks if you have answers ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity: What is the effect of this `othersections` option?

Comment: Honestly I don't remember, but from what I read, it seems to be a non-existing option.

Comment: Is it possible that the only change in beamer would be that the non-existing options were formerly silently ignored and are now brutally rejected ?

Answer (score 3):

I found a dirty workaround here [Keyval undefined error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131091/keyval-undefined-error).

It consists in ignoring the errors coming out of undefined keys :

```
\documentclass[unknownkeysallowed]{beamer}
```