# Package keyval error: Frametitle undefined

Tags: beamer, errors

I'm trying to compile a beamer presentation template but it does not work.

The structure of the code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgf,pgfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}  

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{ift}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\LARGE,series=\bfseries}

\definecolor{uibred}{RGB}{170, 0, 0}
\definecolor{uibblue}{RGB}{0, 84, 115}
\definecolor{uibgreen}{RGB}{119, 175, 0}
%\definecolor{uibgreen}{RGB}{50, 105, 0}
\definecolor{uiborange}{RGB}{217, 89, 0}


\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty


\include{macros}

%\includeonlyframes{current}

\defbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{mycircle}
{
  %\usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
  %\usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0ex}{0ex}{1.5ex}{0ex}
    %\pgfcircle[fill]{\pgfpoint{0pt}{.75ex}}{1.25ex}
    \pgfbox[center,base]{\color{uibblue}\insertenumlabel.}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
[action]
{\setbeamerfont{item projected}{size=\scriptsize}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[mycircle]

\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

I always receive the following message:

```
!Package keyval Error: frametitle undefined. See the keyval package documentation for explanation. 

Type H  for immediate hel..\setbeamersize{frametitle=\huge}
```

I have tried everything and nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

*Obs:** The macro file is given below:

```
%====================================================
%-------------Macro definitions go here--------------
%====================================================

%
% Differentials
%
\newcommand{\tdiff}[2]{\ensuremath{\frac{\mathrm{d}#2}}{\mathrm{d}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\tdifforder}[3]{\ensuremath{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#2}#3}{\mathrm{d}{#1}^{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\pdiff}[2]{\ensuremath{\frac{\partial#2 }{\partial#1}}}
\newcommand{\pdifforder}[3]{\ensuremath{\frac{\partial^{#2}#3}{\partial{#1}^{#2}}}}

% bracket
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\ensuremath{\left<#1\right|}}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\ensuremath{\left|#1\right>}}
\newcommand{\bracket}[2]{\ensuremath{ \left\langle #1 | #2 \right\rangle}}
\newcommand{\matelem}[3]{\ensuremath{ \left\langle #1 | #2 | #3 \right\rangle}}
\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\expectationvalue}[1]{\ensuremath{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}}

\renewcommand{\imath}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{i}}}

%
% Linear algebra
%
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\tildemat}[1]{\ensuremath{\widetilde{\mat{#1}}}}

% Numerical analysis
\newcommand{\bigo}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{O}}}
\renewcommand{\Re}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{Re}}}
\renewcommand{\Im}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{Im}}}
\newcommand{\mathcol}[2]{{\color{#1}#2}}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\mathcol{uibred}{#1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{\mathcol{uibblue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\green}[1]{\mathcol{uibgreen}{#1}}
\newcommand{\orange}[1]{\mathcol{uiborange}{#1}}
%
% Misc macros
%
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{~(\ref{#1})}
\renewcommand{\equiv}[0]{\ensuremath{:=}}
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et al. }}
\newcommand{\paperheader}[2]{\noindent\textbf{Paper #1}: \textit{#2}\\}
\newcommand{\paperitem}[3]{\noindent\textbf{Paper #1}: \textit{#2}\vspace{1em}\\\noindent #3\vspace{2em}}
\newcommand{\tfinal}{\ensuremath{T_{\text{f}}}}
\newcommand{\papernum}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
%\newcommand{\note}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}
\newcommand{\paperref}[1]{Paper~\textbf{#1}}

%
% Code
%
\newcommand{\inlinename}[1]{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily,language=bash]{#1}}
```

The ift theme is defined below:

```
% Based on infolines theme by Till Tantau <tantau@users.sourceforge.net>
%
% This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
% of the GNU Public License, version 2.

\mode<presentation>

\definecolor{lbluegreen}{RGB}{0,84,115}
\definecolor{newitem}{RGB}{253,206,2}
\definecolor{uibred}{RGB}{170,0,0}


\setbeamercolor{section in footer}{fg=white,bg=lbluegreen!95!white}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in footer}{fg=white,bg=lbluegreen!85!white}
\setbeamercolor{pagenumber in footer}{fg=white,bg=lbluegreen!75!white}



\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{ifttheme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.33\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{section in footer}%
    \insertsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.34\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{subsection in footer}%
    \insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.34\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{pagenumber in footer}%
   \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=1em,text margin right=1em}

\mode
<all>
```

**Obs.:** I found the problem and fixed the template. It may be downloaded here
 http://www.4shared.com/zip/OPEgPbYjce/Beamer_Template.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For future reference, these keyval errors can be ignored by passing the option `unknownkeysallowed` to beamer by

```
    \documentclass[unknownkeysallowed]{beamer}
```

as shown in [Keyval undefined error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131091/keyval-undefined-error).